# Unable to execute Northwind bak file in WAMP for a variety of reasons

Tags: mysql, wamp, northwind

Let me start of by saying what I *have* done:

I changed the directory to talk to C: bin\mysql\mysql5.1.53\bin while also moving the Northwind bak file to said location.

At first I tried using mysql.exe -u root -p databasename < databasename.bk
however I kept getting an error saying the file could not be found.

After a bit of research I found a similar script that did not give me the "file could not be found" error, however it did tell me "Access Denied". I apologize I can't seem to find, or remember the exact script I used.

After further research, I did a number of different things such as FLUSH HOST/FLUSH PRIVILEGES but to no avail the "Access Denied" error continues to pop up.

One other thing that I did (trying to import the Northwind bak file directly to phpmyadmin) was change the values in the php.ini folder for maxium_file_size etc etc because of an error I received in phpmyadmin saying the file was too large.

I may have accidentally missed a step or set of instructions, but I am very new to MySQL and WAMP in general. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I remember the NorthWind database is a SQLServer/Access related database. Are you sure what you have is compatible with MYSQL???

Comment: I just looked it up, .bak is only compatible with MS SQLserver. thanks so much! This has been killing me, headaches for a whole day! thanks!